# ExecutorService Java thread limit

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor, java-threads

I am using `ExecutorService` for creating `Thread`. In the `run` method, its processing a time consuming operations. It takes nearly upto 10 seconds to complete it. For testing, here I am using `Thread.sleep(10000);`

My question is, If I use `newFixedThreadPool` as 2000, will it really execute 2000 threads at a time?

```
public class ThreadPoolTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Date());
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2000);
        IntStream.range(0, 2000).forEach(
                i -> {
                    Runnable worker = new WorkerThread("WorkerThread-" + i);
                    executor.submit(worker);//calling execute method of ExecutorService
                }
        );
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {   }

        System.out.println("Finished all threads");
        System.out.println("Main thread finished");
        System.out.println(new Date());


    }
}


public class WorkerThread implements Runnable{

    private String name;
    public WorkerThread(String s){
        this.name=s;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" (Start) message = "+name);
        processData();

    }

    private void processData(){
        try {  Thread.sleep(10000);  } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

}
```

I am printing the time in this code. Its showing that, it took only 10 seconds to complete the entire process. That means all 2000 threads executed parallelly? I have heard that the number of actual threads running will be based on the number of `cores` in the system. But how did all 2000 threads run parallely?

Answer (score 0):

The number of logical CPUs determines the number of threads running at a given moment.

However, a CPU can switch threads every 100 microseconds or about 10,000 times per second giving the illusion more threads are running at once. Calling `sleep` is likely to cause the CPU to context switch until after the timeout.

NOTE: System.out.println holds a lock for the output, so in reality, only one thread at a time is doing real work, and even then the program is probably being slowed down by the speed your screen will update.  Try removing the `println` (and the `sleep`) and it should complete in a fraction of the time.

> But how did all 2000 threads run parallely?

Almost all of them were asleep.  The only busy thread was likely to be the one updating the screen with the buffered `println` messages.